# Обработка исключений

Tags: visual-studio, c#

Здравствуйте!

Обязательно ли, при создании приложения, обрабатывать исключения? И чем хорошо их наличие, и чревато их отсутствие?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не обязательно, но желательно. Их наличие и отлавливание позволит быстрее находить и/или обрабатывать/исправлять ошибки без вылета приложения. При отсутствии обработки исключения приложение при появлении критической ошибки (2/0, к примеру) просто прекратит свою работу.

[Статья на википедии.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#.D0.94.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B0_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B8)

Comment: Я бы еще порекомендовал прочитать главу из книги Trey Nash Accelerated C# 2010 "Exception Handling and Exception Safety".

Answer (score 2):

Если приложение не обрабатывает исключение само, то будет вызван обработчик по умолчанию, который в большинстве случаев приводит к аварийному завершению работы приложения. В зависимости от приложения, это может быть как приемлимо, так и не приемлимо.

Сами исключения позволяют упростить обработку ошибок, когда не нужно в явном виде отслеживать коды возврата из функций.